# "xdg-mime query filetype" returning different filetype than "file --mime-type"

Tags: shell, mime-types

I have a bash script that runs to create emails. I do not wish to modify it for now since it is pretty critical in my current project. One command does not run the same on the operational machine and on mine:

```
xdg-mime query filetype <file>
```

It's running on a simple `us-ascii` encoded text file (with a custome file extension). The thing is, on the operational machine where the script works, it returns `plain/text` (expected behavior). Debug mode of xdg-mime shows that it is actually running a `file -i` command on the operational machine. On my machine though, it returns `application/octet-stream` and runs a `gnomevfs-info` command. It appears to have something to do with the desktop environment (both machines are running on gnome).

Is there a way to force `xdg-mime` to run `file -i`? Or to make `gnomevfs-info` return the correct mime type ? I tried unsetting `GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID` but here is what `xdg-mime` does:

```
detectDE()
{
    if [ x"$KDE_FULL_SESSION" = x"true" ]; then DE=kde;
    elif [ x"$GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID" != x"" ]; then DE=gnome;
    elif `dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus /org/freedesktop/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus.GetNameOwner string:org.gnome.SessionManager > /dev/null 2>&1` ; then DE=gnome;
    elif xprop -root _DT_SAVE_MODE 2> /dev/null | grep ' = \"xfce4\"$' >/dev/null 2>&1; then DE=xfce;
    fi
}
```

The third `elif` is the one that leads to `xdg-mime` using `gnomevfs-info` over `file -i`, because the command returns 0 and DE is set to gnome. I've tried looking at man pages, but that command `dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus /org/freedesktop/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus.GetNameOwner string:org.gnome.SessionManager > /dev/null 2>&1` is jibberish to me.

Comment: Does gnomevfs-info produce an expected result when run in a "slow MIME mode" (`gnomevfs-info --slow-mime my.file) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know your custom text file extension(s) in advance, you can simply register a new MIME entry for them, as a workaround.

E.g. if your files have an extension of ".list":

Prepare the descriptor file: *zeppelin-list.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
  <mime-type type="text/plain">
    <comment>List file type</comment>
    <glob pattern="*.list"/>
  </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

Register a new MIME entry:

```
%xdg-mime install zeppelin-list.xml
```

Query:

```
%xdg-mime query filetype my.list
text/plain
```

Comment: This answers the question exactly, providing a work-around without changing the command. Thank you !

Comment: After implementing it, I can confirm that this solution does work like intended !

Comment: `xdg-mime` on my Mint system was incorrectly identifying PGP keys as Apple Keynote files (`file` gave correct results). This helped me to fix it, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`xdg-mime` is a core component of your desktop environment and you shouldn’t try to change its behavior. I understand your fears to break your mission-critical script, but if it produces different results on the operational machine and on the test machine, it is *already* broken and it has to be fixed. Basically,

```
file -b --mime-type <file>
```

is a drop-in replacement of

```
xdg-mime query filetype <file>
```

and changing it should be painless, especially if your preferred behavior is the output of `file -i`.

The `xdg-*` commands depend by design on the desktop environment you are running in (remember that the prefix stands for ***X** **D**esktop **G**roup*) and, in principle, they shouldn’t be used at all in scripts not meant for user interaction.

If you want exactly the same behavior on all systems, use commands like `file`, which are meant to behave always in the same way (OK, they *might* be small version differences, but that is inevitable).

If you want the “most sensible” behavior for each system, use those wrapper commands like `xdg-mime` and be prepared to adapt to their idea of “most sensible” on each system.

The wrong thing to do is to try to change each environment so that the environment-dependent programs behave the same.

Comment: While your answer is probably the "most correct" in regards to what *should* be done, it does not answer the original request of not changing the script. Nonetheless you provided very interesting insight and I would like to formally thank you for your input (of course I upvoted your answer). Cheers !

Comment: xdg-mime and file do not always give the same results, so it's not a drop in replacement.